# How to debug flowtype extreme slow performance?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

at work I'm forced to use flow type, it is however **extremely** slow, here is a video demonstrating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hloQX8wG0t0

I already tried several things, such as deleting flow-typed definitions, getting rid of circular dependencies, etc...

At this point I'm out of ideas, I also don't know how to debug the thing, does anyone have an idea how to see the dependency tree that is generated after saving/each keystroke?

Edit 1:
Here is my current `.flowconfig`:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/.*
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/picker.*
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider.*
; remove when flow is updated. Currently leads to "Cannot assign rest to restState because rest [1] is incompatible with State [2]."
.*/node_modules/redux-persist/lib/persistReducer.js.flow
.*/node_modules/recompose/dist/Recompose.cjs.js.flow

; Ignores sub apps
.*/firebase/**
.*/webapp/**
.*/node_modules/react-native-androw/src.*

; Migration to RN 0,64 causes some random errors
.*/node_modules/react-navigation-redux-helpers
.*/node_modules/react-navigation-redux-helpers
.*/node_modules/react-native-calendars
; .*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Interaction
; .*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Logbox/Data

; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore polyfills
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/.*

; Flow doesn't support platforms
.*/Libraries/Utilities/LoadingView.js

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/.*/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-confetti-cannon/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/.*


[libs]
node_modules/react-native/interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow/
flow/libs

[options]
emoji=true
server.max_workers=1
sharedmemory.hash_table_pow=22

esproposal.optional_chaining=enable
esproposal.nullish_coalescing=enable
; RN 0.64 turns this on, our codebase explodes
; exact_by_default=true
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.ios.js
module.system.node.allow_root_relative=true
munge_underscores=true
module.name_mapper='^react-native/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-native/\1'
module.name_mapper='^@?[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RelativeImageStub'
module.name_mapper.extension='svg' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/SVGFlowStub.js'

suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe
suppress_type=$FlowFixMeProps
suppress_type=$FlowFixMeState

; Types first is the architecture that forces very very strict rules (always export typed results)
; In order to increase the performance of flow (it is painfully slow)
; However our codebase is in no way shape or form ready for this (it throws around 567 type errors)
types_first=false

[lints]
sketchy-null-number=warn
sketchy-null-mixed=warn
sketchy-number=warn
untyped-type-import=warn
nonstrict-import=warn
deprecated-type=warn
unsafe-getters-setters=warn
unnecessary-invariant=warn
signature-verification-failure=warn

[strict]
deprecated-type
nonstrict-import
sketchy-null
unclear-type
unsafe-getters-setters
untyped-import
untyped-type-import

[version]
^0.137.0
```

I also tried a different flow plugin because I thought it could be related to [the plugin making too many requests to the flow server](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/414), that improves the performance a little bit, but not significantly

Edit 2:

I just tried a bunch of things, namely deleting a bunch of typings that we had for recompose, then also tried extracting a large part of the types to a libDef... still nothing

I really think the problem is our architecture, we basically have declared all of our types in a `types/index.js` file, every time we want to use them we import them manually e.g. `import type { UUID } from 'src/types'`, and since ALL the types are declared there then the dependency tree is not wrong and it needs to check 400+ files on every change/save

## Edit 3

I ended up parsing the entire app's dependency tree to figure out if something was really wrong... came to the conclusion that flow is doing nothing wrong, but our imports are to blame, mostly (I think) due to Redux and Sagas, pulling one import end-ups re-checking the entire app.

You can find my how I figured it out here:

https://ospfranco.com/post/2021/08/25/how-to-visualize-flowtype-dependency-tree/

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some details on flow version and flowconfig?

Comment: You are right, sorry! I added my flowconfig info plus some issues on the vscode plugin repo

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Have you tried removing `server.max_workers`? In my own projects I tend to flow ignore everything, then [unignore](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/ignore/#toc-ignore-exclusions) deps over time if they are flowtyped, everything else I depend on flow-typed defs/stubs. This way I don't get the full load of node_modules to parse, I don't know what performance that would have but I heard it's lesser these days. Also another curious question what are the specs of your machine?

Comment: yes, I have removed the max_workers, I also already tried ignoring all flow-typed dependencies, and I'm running on an m1 air, but the problem was already present in my old i9 15' macbook pro

Comment: Next thing I'd ask is whether this is experienced by your colleagues or just you? Flow's supposed to run on large codebases as that's FB's apparent use case. But could I get you to clone this minimal repo I have and see if it's still slow? This one basically has zero deps and is 2 files https://github.com/Brianzchen/string-literal-repro

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help. I cloned the repo... tried to use the string literals, no slowdown whatsoever. Also yes, the rest of the team also experiences this slowdown

Comment: Great! I guess from all you've told me this comes down to a setup issue of the project itself not necessarily your machine. I recommend 2 final things, have you tried upgrading flow version, performance has improved over time, and seeing as you're using RN, can you ignore more dirs that may be huge but flow needs to parse to find js files?

Comment: Well... yesterday I went a little ballistic and actually parsed and analyzed the entire app's dependency tree, and as it turns out this files (all the Sagas actually) do indeed trigger a 420 file dependency tree... due to our poor usage of imports and probably because the actions live in the same files as the reducers. I'm preparing a blog post to show how I did it, but the behavior seems to be correct, so upgrading flow will not solve it. Maybe, using the type-first architecture will improve it, but the only solution is to solve our crappy import tree. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up parsing the entire app's dependency tree to figure out if something was really wrong... came to the conclusion that flow is doing nothing wrong, but our imports are to blame, mostly (I think) due to Redux and Sagas, pulling one import end-ups re-checking the entire app.

You can find my how I figured it out here:

https://ospfranco.com/post/2021/08/25/how-to-visualize-flowtype-dependency-tree/

Comment: Nice one! Was definitely a good read, glad I could help if not only a tiny bit